# Recovering SSL key from a dead computer

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate

When a server won't boot but you still have a functioning hard drive, you still should be able to extract the stored SSL certificates and keys, right? The information is all there after all.

The system certificates are stored in the registry here:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates`

And the associated private keys are stored here:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Keys\`

But simply importing those keys into the live registry results in certificates with keys that don't work. How do I extract an SSL certificate off a dead drive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It involves more than just the Registry. The locations are described in this MSDN Article: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204778%28VS.85%29.aspx). The blob you see in the registry under "keys" is a metadata blob, not the actual key. The actual key is stored encrypted in the file-system in the All Users profile.

All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

The MSDN article lists where keys are stored for various key-owners.